# Correct class names in IntelliJ debugger (scala)

Tags: scala, class, debugging, intellij-idea

I am new to scala & IntelliJ, so this might sound like a stupid question. However, I see that when debugging, IntelliJ will infer parameter types to some kind of "weird" type, in my case `MapLike$MappedValues`. The expected type would be `Map[String, Iterable[Person]]`.

Why can IntelliJ not display the correct type? Right now this would be kind of important to me, because by debugging I am trying to find out the correct parameter type, because the API documentation on this part is not very clear (working with [Apache Flink CEP](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/libs/cep.html))

Code example:

```
val result:DataStream[String] = patternStream.select(patterns => {
  val person:Person = patterns.head._2.head

  s"Person ${person.name} of age ${person.age} can drink!"
})
```

This is what I can see in the debugger: [image]

According to the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/libs/cep.html#selecting-from-patterns):
*"The select() method takes a selection function as argument, which is called for each matching event sequence. It receives a match in the form of Map[String, Iterable[IN]]"*

Why does IntelliJ display `MapLike$MappedValues` and not something like `Map[String,Iterable[Person]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger is showing you the runtime class.

On the JVM, generic type parameters are "erased" at runtime, so they will not be visible in the debugger. `Map` is just an interface, but `MapLike$MappedValues` implements it as inheritor of `AbstractMap`.

Thus, the displayed *class* is compatible with the *type* of the value.

To find the compile time type of an expression, IntelliJ can help you:

- select the expression
- press the "type info" hotkey (usually shift+ctrl+p)